# Javascript Json: How do I rewrite this array to output in particular format

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I am using the following to gather an array of fields I need to use:

```
 $reqFlds = array();
    $results = mysql_query("aid, fld_name from field
where aid = $acct_id2 and req_flag = 1");
        while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($results))
            {
            $reqFlds[] = $result;
            }

    <script language="javascript">
        var reqFlds= <?php echo "new Array(". trim(json_encode($reqFlds), '[]').")"; ?>;
    </script>
```

**My "reqFlds" array spits out like this:**

```
<script language="javascript">
    var reqFlds = new Array(
    {"aid":"15","fld_name":"Job Issued"},
    {"aid":"18","fld_name":"Job Title"},
    {"aid":"20","fld_name":"Banner Details"},
    {"aid":"202","fld_name":"Flyer Details"},
    {"aid":"2134","fld_name":"Code Not above"},
    {"aid":"5862","fld_name":"Quantity"});

</script>
```

I've been given a function that needs the array data like this:

```
var fldToUse = ['15||Job Issued', '18||Job Title', '20||Banner Details'];
```

How can I rewrite my array [reqFlds] so it spits in the format above:

## Thank you in advance.

**Recent edits - Below is exactly how I have placed the code and the result**

```
<?php
$reqFlds  = array();
$results = mysql_query("select id, display_name from field where account_id = $acct_id2 and required_flag = 1");
    while($RequireResult = mysql_fetch_assoc($results))
        {
            $reqFlds[] = $RequireResult;
        }

foreach($reqFlds as $reqFlds)
    {
    $reqFlds = $reqFlds["id"] . "||" . $reqFlds["display_name"];
}
?>

<script language="javascript">
    var requiredFieldsPRS = <?php echo "new Array(". trim(json_encode($reqFlds), '[]').")"; ?>;
    var holdReqFlds = <?php echo json_encode($reqFlds); ?>;
</script>
```

if leave the code like this with the foreach outside the loop, i only get one this when I view source  - this is so close because is is layed out the way I need, but this is only the first value in the array

```
<script language="javascript">
    var requiredFieldsPRS = new Array("'5862||Quantity'");
    var holdReqFlds = "'5862||Quantity'";
</script>
```

if it put in the array, the entire thing dies

I'm sure i'm just tired and can probably come up with other excuses, but the short is I just don't
what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Why not just return the array in JSON format, instead of explicitly calling new Array();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can *transform* the array in your PHP code like this:

```
$reqFlds = array();
$results = mysql_query("select aid, fld_name from field where aid = $acct_id2 and req_flag = 1");
while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    $reqFlds[] = $result;
}
// at this point the array becomes something like this
//
// array(
//     array("aid" => "15","fld_name" => "Job Issued"),
//     array("aid" => "18","fld_name" => "Job Title"),
//     array("aid" => "20","fld_name" => "Banner Details"),
//     array("aid" => "202","fld_name" => "Flyer Details"),
//     array("aid" => "2134","fld_name" => "Code Not above"),
//     array("aid" => "5862","fld_name" => "Quantity")
// );
//
// here is how you transform array elements to desired format:
foreach($reqFlds as &$reqFld) {
    $reqFld = $reqFld["aid"] . "||" . $reqFld["fld_name"];
}
unset($reqFld);
```

You can then do a:

```
var reqFlds = <?php echo json_encode($reqFlds); ?>;
```

Output:

```
<script>
var reqFlds = ["15||Job Issued","18||Job Title","20||Banner Details","202||Flyer Details","2134||Code Not above","5862||Quantity"];
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Salman I think this is exactly want I am want, but I am not sure I am setting it up correctly.  The foreach, am I correct that you are using this in place of my while statement above?

Comment: The foreach was supposed to go _after_ the while loop. See revised answer.

Comment: Salman I tried your revised answer, but I only get one value from the array.  I updated my code at the top.  Could you at and see if you can see what I am doing wrong please?

Comment: You didn't copy-paste well. Look carefully. There is `reqFld` variable (singular), `&` is used (look closely), do not use `new Array()` (no need, json_encode will create necessary `[]`).

Comment: Good Grief Salmon - thank you - I called myself cleaning out the code and made a big mess in removing that ampersand.  THANK YOU!  I would never have seen that, particularly not after the day I've had.  That got it working.  THANKS AGAIN!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
var newArray = [];

for(var i = 0; i != reqFlds.length; ++i)
{
  newArray.push(reqFlds[i].aid + "||" + reqFlds[i].fld_name);
}
```

newArray will now be in the format you need.  This is a clientside solution.  If you need to change it on the PHP side, then that's a different solution:

```
$reqFlds = array();
    $results = mysql_query("aid, fld_name from field
where aid = $acct_id2 and req_flag = 1");
        while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($results))
            {
            $reqFlds[] = $result['aid'] . '||' . $result['fld_name'];
            }

    <script language="javascript">
        var reqFlds= <?php echo "new Array(". trim(json_encode($reqFlds), '[]').")"; ?>;
    </script>
```

Comment: Instead of `var reqFlds= <?php echo "new Array(". trim(json_encode($reqFlds), '[]').")"; ?>;` you should just write `var reqFlds= <?php echo json_encode($reqFlds); ?>;`

Comment: I agree. I've seen other people suggesting it.  I went with minimal edits (also I'm not a PHP guy ;)).  So +1 to your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. Nice and clean.

```
<?php 
    $reqFlds = array();
    $results = mysql_query("aid, fld_name from field where aid = $acct_id2 and req_flag = 1");

    while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
        $reqFlds[] = $result['aid'] . '||' . $result['fld_name'];
    }
?>

<script language="javascript">
    var reqFlds= <?php echo json_encode($reqFlds); ?>;
</script>
```

Comment: While I agree with what you're suggestion, it doesn't answer his question.

Comment: Actually no, not true.  What he wants is an end result array of strings with value "<AID>||<FLD_NAME>>"  If you update your answer to give him this result in the client-side JS then the answer addresses the issue.

Comment: That part didn't even load until just now. Great, I'll edit a cleaner solution.

Comment: Eli is correct, I need the output of my current code "var reqFlds= <?php echo "new Array(". trim(json_encode($reqFlds), '[]').")"; ?>;" to output in this format "['15||Job Issued', '18||Job Title', '20||Banner Details']" so quote, acct value, pipe, flieldname, quote and so on.

Answer (score 0):

On the client-side you can try:

```
  var reqFlds = new Array(
    {"aid":"15","fld_name":"Job Issued"},
    {"aid":"18","fld_name":"Job Title"},
    {"aid":"20","fld_name":"Banner Details"},
    {"aid":"202","fld_name":"Flyer Details"},
    {"aid":"2134","fld_name":"Code Not above"},
    {"aid":"5862","fld_name":"Quantity"});


var transformed = reqFlds.map(function(item) {
  return item["aid"] + "||" + item["fld_name"];
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sN25z/)

For server-side, Eli's solution looks about right.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
var reqFldsFormatted = new Array();

for (var i=0; i<reqFlds.length; i++) {
    // Written for readability, not execution speed
    reqFldsFormatted[i] = reqFlds[i]["aid"] + "||" + reqFlds[i]["fld_name"];
}
```